# Web Services Client Application

Tags: c#, web-services

my name is Edward Chairez and I'm currently a student in West Texas A&M University. Anyways, my question is, how to create a c# web service cleint application in ASP.net. I Work in an Institute that captures wind data; retrieving this data from https://www.hobolink.com/ and then transforms these data into a X-cel sheet with graphs, averages, etc... But recently, my boss asked me if I was up for a challenging project, and I said yes. The project consists of creating a web service client application to retrieve data from HOBOlink servers, which retrieves data from the Onset HOBO Data Loggers.

The HOBOlink® Web Services API is an application programming interface that enables organizations to easily integrate energy and environmental data from Onset HOBOlink web servers with custom software applications. It will be utilized by a range of users, from building energy dashboard suppliers to developers looking to embed real-time weather data from Onset HOBO® U30 monitoring systems into web-based portals. The HOBOlink Web Services API supports the Simple Object Access Protocol (SOAP) and Representational State Transfer (REST) architectures. Data can be fetched through the web services either in CSV format or SensorML (Sensor Model Language) format, depending upon the type of web service chosen by the user.

my questions are, how do I create this application in c#?
Do I use visual studios to create it and if so, how do I do this, is a Console Application?

here is some code that I got from the Hobo developers, of course non of the credentials are correct:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace TestWebServices2
{
    class TestSensorObservationServiceFull
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            // Development            
            SensorObservationService stub = new SensorObservationService("https://webservice.hobolink.com:missing some information here due to rules and privacy");

            // Stable
            //SensorObservationService stub = new SensorObservationService("https://webservice.hobolink.com/axis2/services/SensorObservationService");

            SosGetObservationRequestFull req = new SosGetObservationRequestFull();
            req.auth = new Authentication();
            req.auth.token = "privacy";
            req.auth.user = "privacy";
            req.auth.password = "privacy";
            string[] serialNumbers = {"privacy"};
            req.serialNumbers = serialNumbers;
            req.timePeriod = new TemporalFilter();
            req.timePeriod.@operator = "During";
            req.timePeriod.time = new TimePeriod();
            req.timePeriod.time.start = new DateTime(2009, 3, 3, 13, 0, 0);
            req.timePeriod.time.end = new DateTime(2009, 3, 3, 14, 0, 0);
            req.timePeriod.time.startSpecified = true;
            req.timePeriod.time.endSpecified = true;
            try
            {
                String result = stub.GetObservationFull(req);
                Console.WriteLine("The result is: " + result);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error: " + e);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Please help me out and walk me through the steps, I'm not required to do this project but I believe it will be a great experience for me!

thanks

Comment: the code you have ... does it work..? if so then my next question is how do you want to consume that code or have other Clients consume that code by Clients I mean applications.. if you want a Web Service.. , Windows Service, Win Forms App, Web Forms App, Silverlight WPF..ect... if you have an existing Web Service or create a new one you can still consume that service.. by Consume I mean adding a reference to your project to access it's public functionality or web methods p.s I am proud to help out my fellow Texan..lol I am in Plano

Comment: Do you have any real-world experience with application development on .net? If not, I'd recommend starting out with a simpler exercise. Programming against a web service without basic experience can be a real pain in the a.., especially if you have to debug across the service boundaries if something doesn't work as expected

Comment: DJ KRAZE, I'm waiting for Visual Studios to finish downloading because I didn't have it on this computer. Once it finish, I will test this code, I just got it today as well. I will let you know if works my fellow Texan. As of the second question, for now I just want to test it in a Web Form or Console Application, simple. But once this test is done and I get more experience, the project will have to look like the https://www.hobolink.com/ but my boss wants me to add other stuff.

Comment: Dennis, I do have experience with application development on .net, I done couple websites for some projects in school, so if you wish to help me, your help will be appreciated by my persona.

Comment: OK, so I created a new project in Visual studios, file->new->project->Console Application, this code will not show any errors, but remember this is the main class, in the other class, where I defined the objects that I'm using in this class, I'm getting errors saying, "The type or namespace name "Services" in the namespace System.Web does not exist, are you missing an assembly reference. here is some code I'm using in the class:

Comment: using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Web.Services;
using System.Web.Services.Protocols;
using System.Xml.Serialization;


[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("wsdl", "privacy")]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Web.Services.WebServiceBindingAttribute(Name="privacy", Namespace="privacy")]
public partial class SensorObservationService : System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol {
    
private System.Threading.SendOrPostCallback.. more code after

Comment: How do I add this reference to my project or how to I fix this error

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that some references got removed? Or some Using statements at the top got removed? Whether you removed them or not, they're gone. Try adding them back. You need System.web. If that doesn't work try setting the "Target Framework" of all the projects to be the same.